# SQL iterating through rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a million records. This is the structure of the table with some example data points -

**INPUT**

```
patient   claim   thru_dt   cd   start     
322       65      20200201  42   20181008  
322       65      20200202  42             
322       95      20200203  52             
122       05      20200105  23             
122       05      20200115  42   20190102  
122       05      20200116  42
```

I need to write a query that would produce this output -

**OUTPUT**

```
patient   claim   thru_dt   cd   start     
322       65      20200201  42   20181008    
322       65      20200202  42   20181008    
322       95      20200203  52   20181008    
122       05      20200105  23               
122       05      20200115  42   20190102    
122       05      20200416  42
```

This is the query that does that -

```
    SELECT t.*, s.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(t.start, '') = '' AND (
            s.cd = t.cd 
            OR 
            (
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.patient ORDER BY t.thru_dt DESC) = 1
            )           
        )
        THEN s.start
        ELSE t.start
    END new_start
FROM table t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT top (1) s.*
    FROM table s
    WHERE 
        s.patient = t.patient 
        AND ISNULL(s.start, '') <> ''
        AND s.thru_dt >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, t.thru_dt)
    ORDER BY s.thru_dt DESC
) s
ORDER BY t.patient DESC, t.thru_dt
```

This query produces the output I need but it doesn't work for this edge case -

**INPUT**

```
patient   claim   thru_dt   cd   start     
322       65      20200201  42   20181008    
322       65      20200202  45      
322       95      20200203  52      
122       05      20200105  23               
122       05      20200115  42   20190102    
122       05      20200416  42
```

The difference between the first input and the second input is the `cd` value of the second row. When I run the above query, the output I get is -

**OUTPUT**

```
patient   claim   thru_dt   cd   start     
322       65      20200201  42   20181008    
322       65      20200202  45   NULL    
322       95      20200203  52   20181008    
122       05      20200105  23               
122       05      20200115  42   20190102    
122       05      20200416  42
```

However, I don't want the third record to have a start value if the second record for patient 322 was given a NULL.

Here is a DBFiddle outlining my issue - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10842c7e66e148dbaad58ccb71cd6c11

**UPDATE**

This is the explanation for the first `output` data block -

The reason the second claim of patient 322 was given `20181008` is because both the first and the second one have the same `cd` value.

The reason the third claim of patient 322 was also given `20181008` value even though it doesn't have the same `cd` value is because it is the last claim for the patient.

The reason the first claim of patient 122 is still a NULL is because that claim's `cd` value is not equal to 42.

The reason the third claim of patient 122 was NOT given a value of `20190102` even though it has the same `cd` value is because the thru_dt in their prior claim is more than 30 days apart.

Comment: Please explain the logic.  Why is the `start` on some rows but not all?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the question. Thank you!

Comment: What is the difference between a row that has `NULL` and one without a value? Surely they are the same, as a date cannot have the value `''`.

Comment: @Larnu The `start` field is a varchar field.

Comment: Your [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10842c7e66e148dbaad58ccb71cd6c11) suggests otherwise, @Doe, and *why* are you using a `varchar` to store a date? Use the correct types; there are 6 different date and time data types, and 5 of them are far more appropriate.

Comment: @Larnu I don't have an option. This application was built before my time.

Comment: That doesn't mean you shouldn't fix it, @Doe .

Comment: @Larnu I would love to fix it but this will break a lot of connected applications if I do. Also, our product team doesn't want to prioritize this effort.

Comment: Is the fiddle updated?

Comment: @SteveC No, it is not. I am working off of the fiddle. If I can get it to work, I can get my code to work too. All I will have to change is `start IS NULL` to `ISNULL(start, '') = ''`